# Domain xyz.com and abc.com redirect to the same address

Tags: apache, dns, iredmail

Let's say I have domains **xyz.com**, **abc.com** and a **server with iRedMail** (a mail server application) - for example it's IP address is 1.2.3.4.

The address **http*s*://xyz.com/mail** is redirecting to iRedMail login page - and that's ok.

In DNS I have A-type redirect from **abc.com** to **1.2.3.4 server**.

In the server I added a  **abc.com** domain rule in apache2 configuration.

Sadly when I type **htt*p*://abc.com** in a browser, the browser redirect me to **http*s*://xyz.com/mail**. But the browser should show me a file from a specific folder (defined in apache2 config).

How can I fix it?

Comment: try virtual hosts: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html#purename

Comment: I've created virtual host for abc.com domain. It's contains everything what is in your link.

I think I should edit xyz.com virtual host, but I don't know how

Comment: there is a tutorial : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts    After setting up files you enable each virtualhost. It is also told in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

the default index.html file will have been replaced by a similar file with a line of html code inside it to redirect any requests to abc.com -> abc.com/mail.

just remove index.html and you'll be fine.